# JSTL tag is not work

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, jstl

I have a JSTL page and I want to print a value. This is my jstl page

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>  

<html>
<head>
<title>Application</title>
</head>

<body>
<c:if test="${parameter!=null}">
    <br>
        <label><c:out value="${parameter}" /></label>
    </c:if>
</body>
```

The problem is that I don't read anything in the page because the code is not print. This is my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Servlet

```
String parameter="hello";

request.setAttribute("parameter", parameter);
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

This is where index.jsp is located in my project:

```
-src
  -main
     -java
     -resources
     -webapp
        -WEB-INF
           -web.xml
        -index.jsp
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Have you set `parameter` in your controller class?

Comment: @mohammedkhan I have edit my question!

Comment: What is The URL being displayed in the location bar of your browser? What is the code displayed when right-clicking and choosing "view page source"?

Comment: A few questions: 
1- "index.jsp" is in root folder?
2- try to use <c:if test="${not empty parameter}">

Comment: @Henrique Fernanedes Cipriano I edited my question and I show you my project folder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also make sure that you added following in jsp file:-

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

EL expression:

```
<c:out value="${requestScope.parameter}"/>
```